# How do I tell LibreOffice to use double spaces (or a free-form margin) for each new sentence?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, whitespace, typography

I have written a long document in LibreOffice. I have written it like this:

> This is a sentence. Now begins another. Here is a third.

That is, one space between each word and between each sentence.

How do I instruct LibreOffice how much I want the space to be between each sentence (not paragraph!) other than manually going through the entire massive document and adding another space after every space in the beginning of each sentence? (Which, by the way, would not let me make the space "one and a half", for example.)

All search results seem to talk about "double line space" rather than "double space", which is not what I'm asking about.

Comment: Does the document contain abbreviations followed by full stops / periods? Is it ok to add additional whitespace after those characters, too?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no bullet-proof solution to modify the [**Sentence spacing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_spacing) in LibreOffice (since LO doesn't know the concept of "sentence", nor does any other word processing software I've encountered so far). So, every solution may affect other places of your document, too.

IMHO, the [best idea is in fact to search/replace existing whitespace](https://superuser.com/a/1554361/84724) (as proposed by Reddy Lutonadio). To do so, you'll have to restrict the modification to whitespace characters that follow after a [full stop/period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop#Abbreviations). If your document contains abbreviations followed by a full stop, too, whitespace following those characters will be affected by a search/replace, too.

If this is ok, then you could replace the space after the full stop by a "[quad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad_(typography))". You may combine multiple quads of different size to achieve the desired amount of spacing. [Unicode offers many different whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) for such a task.

If this doesn't fit your needs, i fear you will have to choose different tools that are better suited for such typographic detail work, e.g. [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX)/[LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX).

Addendum: [Wikipedia on "Sentence Spacing in Digital Media"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_spacing_in_digital_media) tells mentions TeX/LaTeX as only example for a typesetting system that uses a heuristic to recognize sentence endings, typesetting the spaces after them slightly wider than a normal space.